# How can I change multiple line code indentation in Textmate?

Tags: textmate

When I use textmate, I select multiple lines and I press TAB, I would like to change the indentation of my code, rather than deleting it.

Is there a way to change this functionality?

Comment: doesnt work anymore in the most recent stable version...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> also works.

Comment: Handy to know...

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about changing the tab but you can use

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + }

to indent multiple lines of code at the same time.

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + {

pushes it to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I like to hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> and then use the mouse to select a column of text. Then I hit tab to indent the lines.